# How correct is this sentence: "His parents did not approve of our dating because of our age difference, but we did anyway."

Tags: grammar, verbs, do

How correct is this sentence:
"**His parents did not approve of our dating because of our age difference, but we did anyway.**"

If "**did anyway**" refers to "**approve**", how can one approve one's own actions?

Would this sentence also sound right:

**My sister hates swimming but I do every day.**

Answer (score 7):

Obviously "did anyway" *doesn't* refer to "approve" in OP's example, since that makes no sense. But to avoid confusion, we can just introduce the pronoun ***it*** to reference the previously-mentioned gerund noun (***dating*** and ***swimming,*** here)...

> *His parents did not approve of our dating because of our age difference, but we did **it** anyway.*
> *My sister hates swimming but I do **it** every day.*

Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

The sentences are runny and confusing so I would reword as this:

> His parents didn't approve of the two of us dating because of the
> difference in our age. We are dating regardless.

The second sentence is also ambiguous so I wouldn't use it in that structure.

> My sister hates swimming but I do not. I swim everyday.

Comment: You didn’t date because of your age difference. A comma is needed. They didn’t approve of your dating, because of your age difference.

Comment: What would be wrong with: "His parents did not approve of our dating because of our age difference, but we date anyway."

Comment: @So_about_that - I find that "The sentences are runny and confusing". 
That is why I recommended something that would clear up the confusion. Short sentences are easier to follow and less ambiguous

Comment: I guess I'm just confused about what it is that is causing confusion. I genuinely see no circumstances where a reader or listener would take the meaning of an age difference between kids and parents, nor who is dating whom. It seems perfectly intelligible to me.

Comment: I've never seen a sentence described as "runny". Eggs and glue, maybe. Although I'd prefer "go" with "swimming", they're all intelligible just not especially idiomatic.